# Adding multiple list of an object then view them in datagridview and all the rows of gridview will be passed to array object of web method?

Tags: c#, list, web-services, datagridview

I am trying to enable the user to pass multiple documents to the web methods of web service. I can pass one document but i don't know the best way to pass more than one document.

1. The user can input one document with its details easily.
2. I have created the same object with list in order to enable the user to pass unlimited number of documents
3. I can make more than object for multiple documents but i prefer to make it dynamically instead of restricting it to a particular number of documents
4. The details of document will be viewed in the gridview but when i pass the object variable to array object of the web method, it is showing that "can't implicitly convert a type of list to object.

```
//Object of the document in the web service
Document doc = new Document();
doc.DocCode = docCode.Text;
doc.DocName = docname.Text;
doc.DocLocation= docloc.Text;

//the above doc object will be passed to array of document in web service
service.Documents = new Document[]
{
doc
};

//Another tried Way but i want the user to pass multiple details of document at the same time
List<Document> docs = new List<Document>();
docs.Add(New Document()  {DocCode=docCode.Text, DocName = docname.Text, DocLocation = docloc.Text});

//To enable the user to check the details entered before passing to the web method
gridview1.DataSource = docs;
gridview.DataBind();

foreach (DataGridItem row in gridview1.Rows)
{
    docs.ToArray();
}
//Showing an error than cant implicitly convert from list type to Document
service.Documents = new Document[]
{
docs
};
```

The details of document will be entered by the user using the text boxes and will be viewed in the gridview. Then, all the rows of the gridveiws will be passed to the array object of the document.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to put the array of docs into service.Documents. You received an error, because you can put there elements like this:

```
service.Documents = new Document[]
{
    doc, doc
};
```

But you cannot put there an object of array.
Try something like this:

```
service.Documents = docs.ToArray();
```

Comment: I dont want to make many objects like this: 
`
service.Documents = new Document [] { doc1, doc2, doc3}; 
` 
I want to use list list like the following 
`
service.Documents = new Document[] { docs}; 
` 
but i am receiving an error that you cant implicitly convert type list to object